# Is there any way to check if what i'm adding to the value of a cell is already in the cell?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have multiple macro's that input value's into the cells in a workbook. This is the relevant part that I'm having trouble with:

```
If wsCsh.Cells(cshrow, cshcol) = "" Then
      Cells(cshrow, cshcol - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "='WREG'!R" + CStr(wregrow) + "C" + CStr(wregcol)
Else
      Cells(cshrow, cshcol - 1).FormulaR1C1 = Cells(cshrow, cshcol).FormulaR1C1 + "+'WREG'!R" + CStr(wregrow) + "C" + CStr(wregcol)
End If
```

If the cell(cshrow,cshcol) is empty, it enters in the R1C1 formula to link it to the cell(wregrow,wregcol), if it isn't then it adds cell(wregrow,wregcol) to whatever is in the cell. However, say I run this macro twice in a row. Then it will basically add cell(wregrow,wregcol) to the cell twice so cell(cshrow,cshcol) ends up looking like "=cell(wregrow,wregcol)+cell(wregrow,wregcol)". How can I check if a cell is already referenced in the R1C1 formula so I can avoid adding the value a second time?

Comment: First: Please do not use "`+`" for text ("`&`" is better for several reasons). And to run the check, just use `instr()` to check if `"'WREG'!R" & CStr(wregrow) & "C" & CStr(wregcol)` is part of `Cells(cshrow, cshcol).FormulaR1C1` ;)

Comment: Thanks that ended up working for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim extraBit As String

With wsCsh
    extraBit = "+'WREG'!R" & wregrow & "C" & wregcol
    If .Cells(cshrow, cshcol).Value = "" Then
        'Set the formula to the "extra bit"
        .Cells(cshrow, cshcol - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & extraBit
    ElseIf Right(Cells(cshrow, cshcol - 1).FormulaR1C1, Len(extraBit)) <> extraBit Then
        'Add the "extra bit" if the current formula doesn't already end with it
        .Cells(cshrow, cshcol - 1).FormulaR1C1 = .Cells(cshrow, cshcol).FormulaR1C1 & extraBit
    End If
End With
```